# XMLTable - xpath 'empty()' alternative in Oracle 10g

Tags: xml, xpath, plsql, xml-parsing, oracle10g

In Oracle 11, I have a query like this:

```
SELECT XML_TABLE.*
  FROM XML_DATA,
       XMLTABLE('//root' PASSING XML_DATA.XML COLUMNS
                NAME VARCHAR2 (50) PATH '//root/name/text()',
                HAS_DOCUMENT NUMBER PATH 'empty(//root/document)') XML_TABLE
```

But the XPATH 'empty(//root/document)' not work in a 10g database.

What is the alternative? I try with 'count(//root/document)' (supported in XPATH 1.0), but also does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround.

XML:

```
<root>
  <name>text</name>
  <document id="1">
    <other_tags></other_tags>
  </document>
</root>
```

SQL:

```
SELECT XML_TABLE.NAME,
       DECODE (XML_TABLE.FIRST_ID, NULL, 0, 1) AS HAS_DOCUMENT
  FROM XML_DATA,
   XMLTABLE('//root' PASSING XML_DATA.XML COLUMNS
            NAME VARCHAR2 (50) PATH '//root/name/text()',
            FIRST_ID NUMBER PATH '//root/document[position()=1]/@id') XML_TABLE
```

It is not pretty, I admit. But it worked.